# Hugo static site - issue trying to loop through multiple sub sub folders and returning one sorted list

Tags: go, hugo

I have a folder in “content” called “projects” which has sub folders and also sub-sub folders. I’m trying to get the latest 12 pages content of all the sub-sub folders to show in a single list by date order. (see illustration below)

[image]

My current code (that doesn’t quite work):

```
<ul>
    {{ range .Sections }}
        <li><a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
            {{ range .Sections }}
                {{ range first 12 .Pages }}
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ .RelPermalink}}">{{ .Title }}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                {{ end }}
            {{ end }}
        </li>
    {{ end }}
</ul>
```

This shows the first 12 pages from each sub-sub section. I need to get them all in one list and only show the latest 12 regardless or which sub-sub section they are in.

(This is on a list.html template and needs to be dynamic if it makes a difference - the folders could be called anything)

Cheers,
A.

Answer (score -1):

if what you are looking for is listing 12 pages from each 'main' section, this should work:

```
<ul>
    {{ range .Site.Sections }}
        {{ range first 12 .Pages }}
            <li><a href="{{ .RelPermalink}}">{{ .Title }}</a></li>
        {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
</ul>
```

[Reference](https://gohugo.io/variables/site/#site-variables-list)

Comment: Hey @mshjri thanks for the code but this doesnt help as we ARE looking for the context to be at the top folder level (see example image above).

Comment: hi @Adi, please check the update i posted. If I got you right, it should work.